# Dynamic Div ID and Creating Elements Inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic Div where i can import values from the **showModalDialog** when it is closed. So after closing the modal, i get couple of values.

What i am trying to do here is:

1. I have couple of dynamic div's and against each div, i have a link to open a window.
2. After selection of the files they are return back to the parent window as comma separated.
3. I want to insert those values inside the div to which that popup was opened. but in this scenario i am facing the trouble. the Divid's are generated dynamically

Here is the Complete Code for **Javascript + Jquery** Based, I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: theDiv.appendChild is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

theDiv.appendChild(newNode);

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function eliminateDuplicates(arr,divID) 
{   
    var i,       
    len=arr.length,       
    out=[],       
    obj={};    
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) 
    {     
        obj[arr[i]]=0;   
    }   
    for (i in obj) 
    {     
        out.push(i);   
    }   
    return out; 
}
function GetElementsStartingWith(tagName, subString) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if (element.id && element.id.substr(0, subString.length) == subString) {
            result.push(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
Test= function(str,divID) 
{
    var arrID = new Array();
    arrID = str.split(',');                  
    arrID = eliminateDuplicates(arrID);            
    var theDiv = $("#projectsList"+divID).attr('id'); //document.getElementById('projectsList'); 
    alert(theDiv);
    var cmp= $("#projectIDS"+divID).val(); //document.getElementById("projectIDS").value;
    var cnp = $("#countProj"+divID);//document.getElementById("countProj")  
    var cproj;
        if(cnp.val().length == 0)
            cproj=0;
        else
         cproj=parseInt(cnp.val());

    for (var j=0; j<arrID.length; j++)
    {  
        if (parseInt(cproj) + 1 > 50)
        { 
            alert("You cannot add more than 50 Project id's ");
            return;
        }
        if( cmp!="" && cmp.indexOf(arrID[j])!=-1)
        continue;
        var newNode = document.createElement('div');  
        newNode.style.cssText = "background:#CCCCCC;border:1px solid #666666;width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;margin:3px;float:left;color:black;text-decoration:none!important;height:auto;vertical-align:middle;padding-top:2px;";    
        newNode.title = arrID[j]+" ";
        newNode.innerHTML = '<input type=hidden name=Proj_' + j + ' ' + 'value=' + arrID[j] + '>' + arrID[j] + ' <a href="#" title="Remove Project" onclick="removetext($(this).parent());"><b>X</b></a>';   
        theDiv.appendChild(newNode);
        if(cmp.length == 0) 
            {
                //document.getElementById("projectIDS").value=arrID[j]
                $("#projectIDS"+divID).val(arrID[j]);
            }
        else
            {
                //document.getElementById("projectIDS").value = document.getElementById("projectIDS").value+","+arrID[j];
                $("#projectIDS"+divID).val($("#projectIDS"+divID).val()+","+arrID[j]);
            }
            cproj = parseInt(cproj)+1;  
        //document.getElementById("countProj").value =cproj; 
        cnp.value(cproj);
    }  
}
removetext = function(par)
{
    var strremove=par.text();
    var strexist = document.getElementById("projectIDS").value;
    strremove = strremove.replace(" X","");
    tempRemove(strexist, strremove);
    par.remove();
    var cproj;
        if(document.getElementById("countProj").value.length == 0)
            cproj=0;
        else
         {cproj=parseInt(document.getElementById('countProj').value);

        cproj=parseInt(cproj)-1;}                       
        document.getElementById("countProj").value =cproj;   
}

function tempRemove(strexist,strremove)
{
    var b = strexist.indexOf(strremove);
    var after = strexist.indexOf(",",b);
    var newstrexist;
    var before = strexist.lastIndexOf(",",b);
    if(after!=-1)
    {newstrexist=strexist.replace(strremove+',',"");}
    else if(before!=-1)
    {newstrexist=strexist.replace(','+strremove,"");}
    else
    {newstrexist= strexist.replace(strremove,"");}

    document.getElementById("projectIDS").value=newstrexist;
    //remove current friend
}
function openWindow(divID)
{
    var lookUpAlys=window.showModalDialog("files.cfm?d=" + Math.random() + '&fileID=' + divID,window,"center=yes;dialogWidth:895px:dialogHeight:785px;status:no");
    if(lookUpAlys.forename!=undefined)  
    { 
        var temp = lookUpAlys.forename;
        Test(temp,divID);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Choose</td>
    <td>Files</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </tr>
  <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
  <cfoutput>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="getFile" id="getFile" value="#i#" /></td>
    <td><div id="projectsList#i#" style="width:500px;height:60px;overflow-y:scroll;border:1px solid gray;"></div><input type="text" name="projectIDS#i#" id="projectIDS#i#" data-id="#i#" value="" /><input type="text" data-id="#i#" name="countProj#i#" id="countProj#i#" value="" /></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openWindow(#i#);">Files</a></td>
  </tr>
  </cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

so my apologies if i had entered the code incorrectly. Basically trying do it Classic Javascript Way

Comment: Odd mix of jQuery and non-jQuery code. There's indeed no appendChild method for jQuery object, use `append()` instead

Comment: Hi mishik, es i have edited the code as per suggestion by @Dogbert and it seems working now, only issues now i am left with is the removetext and TempRemove functions which is using a bit of jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not do what I think you think it does:

```
var theDiv = $("#projectsList"+divID).attr('id'); //document.getElementById('projectsList');
```

You should do

```
var theDiv = $("#projectsList"+divID)[0];
```

to get the DOM element.

Or, for this scenario, just do

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("projectsList" + divID);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are mixing raw DOM operations and jQuery wrapped operations everywhere. Just stick to one of them, and be consistent.

Comment: Thanks! I want to e consistent, but the only issue is i do not much of javascript and worked more with jquery. I liked the Last Scenario Let me Try if that works through classic javascript

Comment: That's Cool, With Classic javascript, I am able to do it, Cheers. Now if you see the removeText and tempremove have bit of Jquery written , how can i amend it to classic javascript so as my whole solution could be in javascript

Comment: @GurpreetRandhawa, some pointers: `$(this).parent()` can be replaced by `this.parentNode` if you just want to send the raw DOM node. Then `.text()` by `.innerText`, and `remove()` can be done using a combination of `parentNode and removeChild` - you should Google around for more info.

Comment: Ok solved, just had to add `par.parentNode.removeChild(par);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = $('.itemsList');
var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
//assigning id to div
$(divSubmit).attr('id','itemTemplate');
$(divSubmit).css({"font-family":"Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif","position":"relative","height": "70px","clear" : "both","background-color":"#FFF","border-bottom": "0.09em solid #EBEBEB"});
//adding class to main container
$(divSubmit).addClass('itemTemplate');
//adding Child's name label and assigning id to it.
var Name = '<label class="lblName" id="lblName" for="Name">'+getName()+'</label>';
$(divSubmit).append(Name);
$(divSubmit).append(container);
```

Here's a sample code. first of all there is sample container called itemslist
that will contain the generated div.
divSubmit will be gernerate dynamically and append to container.
To find some div for click event. Lets say we want to get child name.

```
alert($($(this).find("label.lblName")).val());
```